# What's causing the error "gulpSass.compiler.render is not a function" for me?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to setup a gulp task using gulp-sass and when I try and run the task, I'm getting the following error:

`TypeError: gulpSass.compiler.render is not a function`

Which points to index.js in the gulp-sass folder.

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

sass.compiler = ('node-sass');

var cssConfig = {
    src: './wwwroot/src/sass/*.scss',
    dest: './wwwroot/dist/css/'
}

gulp.task('compileSass', function () {
     gulp.src([cssConfig.src])
         .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
         .pipe(gulp.dest([cssConfig.dest]));
});
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0"
  }
}
```

Have I missed something?

So far I've stripped out all of my other tasks and reinstalled all packages just to be on the safe side. But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sass.compiler = ('node-sass');` was the issue. Removed and now ok.